# How to switch to an Activity using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, scope

I have a class file MainActivity and i want switch to Testing.class file. So this is following code.

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);

        final TextView tt=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        Button button=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);


        View.OnClickListener sx = new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                call();

            }

        };

        button.setOnClickListener(sx);


        return rootView;


    }


        private void call()
        {

                     // Here getting the Error //

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Testing.class); 



            startActivity(intent);


        }



   }
```

So, this is the above code , i want to switch to new class file called **Testing** but

i am facing an error-: **No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope**

I think creating an new static class called MyFragment within MainActivity creating problem.

So, please help me out and give me some good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you cannot call  MainActivity.this since you are in the fragment class. You have to access the context in a different way. Such as

```
getActivity()
```

which returns the activity associated with the fragment. The activity is a context (Since Activity extends Context)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActivity()` method inside your fragment but take care that this method might return null in case of calling it before getting `onActivityCreated()` method